# retrieving a matched name video in MediaElement control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video, wpf-controls

i want to play the video which name is entered in text box. But it does not play the exact video it plays the first video present in folder. any help please..

**Code**

```
        String vid_name = data.Text;
        string complete_name = vid_name.ToLower() + ".mp4";
        string root = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("D:/abc");
        string[] supportedExtensions = new[] { ".mp4" };
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(root, "Videos"), "*.*").Where(s => supportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s).ToLower()));

        List<VideosDetail> videos = new List<VideosDetail>();

        VideosDetail id;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            id = new VideosDetail()
            {
                Path = file,
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(file),
                Extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
            };


            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
            id.FileName = fi.Name;
            id.Size = fi.Length;
            videos.Add(id);
             if (id.FileName == complete_name)
            {
          VideoList.ItemsSource = videos; //**Problem comes here
            } 
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no such video is available. ");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since videos is a List, the line

VideoList.ItemsSource = videos;

Points to all the videos in the folder (up to the one that actually matches the filename you entered). Hence, the unwanted result.

You should probably pass the index of the video in your list, something like:

player.Source = videos[x];

Hope this helps!